# QueryOver Many to Many Items

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, queryover

I have 2 entities, linked via a Many to Many called Parent and Child.

In Child I have an IList of Parents,

In Parent I have an IList of Childs.

I am trying to do a query on a list of parents, that is linked to a child.

Conceptually wise, I am looking for something like this:

```
var Query = session.QueryOver<Parent>()

Query.Where(o => o.Children.Contains(child));
```

But this won't work, so what ways can I get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use JoinQueryOver

```
session.QueryOver<Parent>().JoinQueryOver<Child>(p => p.Childs)
       .Where(c => c.Id == child.Id)
```

Comment: hi, just wondering, does joinqueryover result in a query based on child instead? or could I still do a .List<Parent>()?

Answer (score 2):

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Parent>()
    .Where(o => o.Children.Contains(child));
```

or

```
var query = session.Query<Parent>()
    .Where(o => o.Children.Contains(child));
```

or see Vadim

Comment: I didn't know you could do that without an explicit join.

Comment: some methods are supported, especially from LINQ but you have to try every time

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't compile. `Any` takes a lambda not an object.